# What is ".foo{}" in the beginning of a stylesheet?

Tags: css, syntax

I would like to know what is the meaning of ".foo{}"

It is placed at the beginning of a css stylesheet i have been modifying.

Comment: It means you should add a .bar{} at the end of the CSS file if there is none, yet ;-)

Comment: @Joscha There's no need to be misleading.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: all right: @juanmanuelrojascavaliere I was just fooling around, .foo{} was most likely forgotten by a developer working on that particular CSS file earlier and has no special meaning. For further information take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUBAR)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a CSS block modifying the class `foo`.

So, every tag in the HTML file with `class="foo"` would be affected by that CSS block, which in your case does nothing, with what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

all elements with the `foo` class have the style between the curly brackets after that (none)

Answer (score -3):

Applies style to any HTML element with class "foo".

HTH.

Comment: I think I have answered the question & a little humor goes un-appreciated :)

Comment: @Sunny there is the chance that the OP may take you seriously though.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted, and an identical answer massively upvoted?

Comment: @Pekka In the edit history, there's a much less helpful version of the answer

Comment: @Pekka, yes. I wondered that. Then I caught @Rowland Shaw's comment (and +1'd him for it).